# Multiple matches separated by arbitrary text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match the same hashtag separated by arbitrary strings. So

> Lorem Ipsum ***#molecule*** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has ***#Molecule*** been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book ***##Molecule***. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of ***@Molecule*** Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

How can I do this? This regular expression `(\#[Mm]olecule)` patently does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `([#@]+[Mm]olecule)` regex and there is no need to escape `#` and get the matched group at index 1.

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xC8mJ3)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [12-21]     `#molecule`
MATCH 2
1.  [101-110]   `#Molecule`
MATCH 3
1.  [265-275]   `##Molecule`
MATCH 4
1.  [450-459]   `@Molecule`
```

---

Here is sample code with ignore case as well directly from [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xC8mJ3) site.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([#@]+molecule)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = ...

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Not sure why you removed the post match grouping. I wanted all the matching hashtags to be grouped into one as you had first done.

Comment: What do you mean post match grouping?

Comment: Try with sample code. If it doesn't work then let me know I'll update it again.

Comment: @hwnd The original regular expression was `/([#@]+[Mm]olecule)/g`, which did exactly what I wanted, basically a lookahead for all matches of that pattern.

Comment: If your using python then why do you need those delimiters ?

Comment: Does python supports `g`? I don't have any idea about python. When I looked at the generated code by the site for python then it was not there so I removed it from my regex pattern as well.

Comment: I think `findAll()` looks for all the matches.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match either one of those characters.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[#@]+(?i)molecule', data)
['#molecule', '#Molecule', '##Molecule', '@Molecule']
```

**Note**: Used the [inline `(?i)` modifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) to enable case-insensitive matching.

Comment: Does not match two hastag version `##Molecule`

Comment: @dawg Typo, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah you and @Braj have it right, with different side-effects, let me see if there are some +1s in my pocket. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s="""
Lorem Ipsum #molecule is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.    Lorem Ipsum has #Molecule been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book ##Molecule. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of @Molecule Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
"""


print re.findall("@+molecule|#+molecule",s,re.IGNORECASE)
['#molecule', '#Molecule', '##Molecule', '@Molecule']
```

Comment: This matches any hashtag; he stated the same hashtag.